# Bootstrap landing page - tag override?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fullscreen

Hoping someone can help me with a body tag overide I'm having trouble with. Here's the page I'm working on: http://www.designbyantony.com/JMP%20Bootstrap/index.html

I'm trying to set a responsive full screen background image to this (homepage only) by using the full.css file linked to the page. I've attached a screenshot of what I'm aiming for - the image is the jpg marked up in full.css. I was hoping this css file would override any other body declarations in the other css files but it's not working. I have tried assigning a body ID to this page ( etc) but this hasn't worked either - and I disgarded it. I know this is a specificity issue but I can't figure this out. Oddly the background image shows up in DW CS6 design preview (never to be relied on I guess) but not in the browser.

Thanks for taking the time to read this - h[image]oping someone can at least steer me in the right direction.

Thanks, Antony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try to change you css for body tag in full.css file to

```
  background-image: url('../images/john-landing.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Or as the shorthand `background: url('../images/john-landing.jpg') no-repeat center center cover`

Comment: Hi both - that worked great, thank you. Just one thing though: at mobile sizes - how could I ensure the top of the image isn't clipped off by the nav bar? Looks fine at tablet size.